# How to save the correct location of file in table? getting error is not a valid virtual path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image-uploading

I was trying to upload some images in my website using input type=file in my asp.net mvc project.while storing the image I used the following code and it is saving the image successfully.

```
var path2 = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images"), filename.jpg);
artwork.SaveAs(path2);
```

After that I need to save the whole link ( http://example.com/Images/filename.jpg) into my table column.
for that i tried this

```
tablename.imagelink = path2 ;
```

then in table column I am getting  like
     D:\xxxxx\yyyy\example\Images\filename.jpg
then i tried to save the whole link directly
    tablename.imagelink = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("http://example.com/Images/"), filename.jpg);
at that time I am getting an error: "is not a valid virtual path error"
How to solve this. ?

Answer (score 1):

`Server.MapPath` requires the virtual path of the web server, and you get the error because you're passing the full path like this:

```
Server.MapPath("http://example.com/Images/")
```

You need to keep using this:

```
Server.MapPath("~/Images")
```